# redirect 301 - page for page (apache) html to htm and non www

Tags: xml, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

The server is apache, not that I know what that means.

needs/notes:

1. redirect all visits to www.oldsite.com and oldsite.com to www.newsite.com
2. old site uses .html extension and new site uses .htm
3. about half the file names in the new site match those of the old site so I need to specify the redirect for each page.

Here is a sample code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

redirect 301 /index.html http://www.newsite.com/index.htm

redirect 301 /pagetwo.html http://www.newsite.com/pagetwo.htm

redirect 301 /pagethree.html http://www.newsite.com/thishasanewname.htm
```

Currently this does work for the home page when types as www only but thats it. Can anyone help by telling me how to achieve all my goals in one:

To summarize I need to redirect all traffic from old site to new site where the html file names do not always match, I have started using the .htm extension where the old site uses .html and I need visits to both www. and non www version of old site to redirect to www version of new site.

Please help me out someone - I'm not a coder and this stuff is really difficult for me

Doug

Comment: HTTP redirects with apache are very powerful - you should probably take the time to learn how they work, otherwise you'll always be wondering how to achieve something like this. There are a lot of good tutorials online, try reading a few! It will make you a better programmer.

Comment: I'd love to and I'm trying - I'm learning html5, css3 and js right now and it's overwhelming but I enjoy it. Between books and stackoveflow I'm teaching myself and I love that - when there are resources like this you know its the right choice

Answer (score 1):

Replace the rules in your .htaccess above with the ones below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#1 Redirect home page old->new
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.com$ [NC] 
#send home page from old to new
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newsite.com [L,R=301]

#2 place redirects here that do not have exact equivalents on newsite

#3 section
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.com$ [NC] 
#send requests for html to htm (assuming everything else is the same)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+\.htm)l[NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com%1 [L,R=301]
```

**Section #1** will redirect the home page of the old site to the home page of the new.

**Section #3** will redirect `http://oldsite.com/anypage.html` to `http://newsite.com/anypage.htm`

**Section #2**
If there are files that do not have exact equivalents on the new site (minus the .html -> .htm) as in #3, then place then here before #2 e.g.

```
Redirect 301 /pagethree.html http://www.newsite.com/thishasanewname.htm
```

Comment: cheers it's redirecting both www and non www version to new site, html pages to htm pages, unique page for page redirects working except: firefox will not redirect non www version? The other browsers do.. any ideas?

Comment: @DougFirr The redirects should not be browser specific. Try to see differences between http traffic on Firefox vs IE etc using something like Fiddler